# My max-width media query is applying when it shouldn't

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to make a site responsive for the iPhone 7. The problem is that my media query is working when it shouldn't; for iPhone 7, I'm using `max-width: 320px` but his real resolution is **375px** (at least as it show in https://mydevice.io/devices/), so why is my media query applying? 375px is bigger than 320px

```
/* iPhone 7 */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
.qr_popup {
  left: 50%;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ededed;
  width: 85%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;}}

/* Galaxy */
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
.qr_popup {
  left: 50%;
  top: 250px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ededed;
  width: 85%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;}}
```

the different is in the **top: 250px;**

Comment: I dont think it is needed to create  a new mediaquery with onyl 30px difference. Maybe its best to to a mobile first aproach. Start with the smallest mediaquery and build up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your second media query will be applied to any viewport that is **at least** 360px wide, the iPhone 7 as you have stated is 375px.

360px is **less than** 375px so the second media query is applied.

---

FWIW I wouldn't target specific devices (unless you have an urgent need to). I'd start small and add breakpoints as your content and layout dictate when the viewport es enlarged.

Comment: the different is in the top: 250px; and no, the first media query is applied on my iphone7, and that not according the code, really weird

Comment: Then you have something else bleeding through. You should create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).